# Why is it that score is used in singular when referring to several groups of 20?

Tags: grammatical-number

If I'm not mistaken, score can mean "a group or set twenty".

What I don't understand is why you say for example "Four score and seven years ago...", instead of saying "four scores" (since there are four groups of twenty years).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The word **score** follows the same rule that applies for the words **dozen**, **hundred**, **thousand** and **million**. When they are used with a number to denote exact quantity, their form doesn't change, e.g. we say *two hundred, ten thousand, three dozen, five million.*

The plural form with these words is used when the number denoted isn't exact and we just want to emphasise the fact that there are many items, e.g. *hundreds of years ago, dozens of times,* etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hadn't thought about it that way, but after reading your answer it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same reason we don't say "Two hundreds dollars".  The number, whether *twenty* or *eleven thousand three hundred*, refers to the years, not to the 'groups of years'.  Nobody would say **four tens years*; you can say *four decades*, precisely because a *decade* is ten years. But *a score* is just twenty and cannot (in this sense) be pluralized.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You've mentioned the case that I had in mind. I got confused thinking that if Lincoln had used in his speech the term decade instead of score, he would have used the plural form. Your answer, as well as the one given by Irene, make the difference between those words clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to piggy-back on an old question.  But this one has all the foundation for mine, so...

Mine is this:  do we, or do we not, use "of" with score.  I always want to put "of" in, which sounds right to my ear--but sounds wrong according my understanding of the word's usage:

a dozen doughnuts
a score (of?) doughnuts

Two score sheep blocked the road.
Two score of sheep blocked the road.

Comment: Please don't post new questions as answers to other questions. You can use the "Ask Question" button on the homepage to create a new question and you can link to this question for context.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420201)